# Can't install sbt and scala correctly on Linux Mint

Tags: linux, scala, installation

I tried to install sbt and scala accord to it documentation [Setup sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Setup.html) for Unix:

- I created `~/bin`
- Make sbt file with contents:

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> SBT_OPTS="-Xms512M -Xmx1536M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256M"
> java $SBT_OPTS -jar `dirname $0`/sbt-launch.jar "$@"
> ```

- Make the script executable:

  `$ chmod u+x ~/bin/sbt`

But when I run I caught next message:

```
nazar_art@nazar-art-System-Product-Name ~/bin $ sbt
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x0000000088000000, 536870912, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 536870912 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /tmp/hs_err_pid2832.log
```

I couldn't figure out if I did smt wrong, coz `sbt -h` - works ok (it shows info message).

- ***How to solve this trouble?***

Comment: How much RAM your machine have?

Comment: @om-nom-nom My RAM is 1 Gb

Comment: You're instructing sbt to have 512 Megabytes or memory as **minimum** size of heap. Likely there is no that much **free** memory. Try to lower value of Xms parameter (say, to 128M) and see if this works.

Comment: And by the way, I would lower XmX parameter as well, which stands for **maximum** heap size (right now it is 1.5G whereas you only have 1G). Set it to 512M or 768M

Comment: Is `apt-get install scala sbt` out of question?